# Which Android phones support MiFare Classic NFC tags?

Tags: hardware, nfc

I have to use `MiFare Classic NFC` tags, which Android phones can read and write to it? Couldn't find it on the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a source for both `Mifare Classic` and `Mifare Ultralight`, published last month

[Smartphones and Tablets Compatible with NFC Tags](http://www.shopnfc.it/en/content/7-nfc-device-compatibility)